# PostgreSQL Division by ZERO

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to perform division in a SELECT clause. When I join some tables and use aggregate function I often have either null or zero values as the dividers. As for now I only come up with this method of avoiding the division by zero and null values.

select
 date_part('week', startmeasurement::date) AS week,

```
       (COUNT(CASE WHEN new_spm.status IN ('Closed','Resolved')THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    *100/count(case when new_spm.status !='Cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)::double precision) AS percentage_closed_and_resolved

from new_spm

WHERE new_spm.divisi='CNOS-HQ'

GROUP BY week;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: welcome to SO. please update your post to have  a question

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the COALESCE expression available in postgresql. It should significantly simplify your current approach.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html